# Add application in android phone setting

Tags: android

I need to add my application name in android phone system setting, with option to change some configuration of application. Is it possible, how?

Comment: yes its possible you need to set up account for it but its used to sync data async like facebook and google does

Comment: he says changing configuration of the application.That is not possible

Comment: My app open URL in webview. And there are 3 URL. I need to select it from phone setting. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**

That is not possible.Please do more research regarding a question before posting here.

**EDIT:**

You didnt tell which sort of setting.Only if your app does some syncing,you can add "Your App" in the Sync settings

Comment: My app open URL in webview. And there are 3 URL. I need to select it from phone setting. Can it be possible?

Comment: No,i do not know of any way to do that.Mark it as an answer please